# How to fix No package 'atk-bridge-2.0' found error even though atk is installed and PKG_CONIG_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set?

Tags: gtk

First I have installed all the dependent packages including atk 2.18.

Then, I have added them to path.

```
# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/at-spi2-atk/lib:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/gobject-introspection/lib:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/pango/lib:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/harfbuzz/lib:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/freetype/lib:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/icu4c/lib:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/cairo/lib:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/fontconfig/lib:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/libpng/lib:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/pixman/lib:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/atk/lib:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/gdk-pixbuf/lib:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/GLib/lib:

# echo $PATH
/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/gobject-introspection/bin:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/pango/bin:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/harfbuzz/bin:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/freetype/bin:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/which/bin:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/icu4c/sbin:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/icu4c/bin:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/cairo/bin:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/fontconfig/bin:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/libpng/bin:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/gdk-pixbuf/bin:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/GLib/bin:/opt/python_2_7_11/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

# echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/at-spi2-atk/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/gobject-introspection/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/pango/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/harfbuzz/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/freetype/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/cairo/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/fontconfig/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/libpng/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/pixman/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/atk/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/gdk-pixbuf/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies/GLib/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/gtk_+3.12-RHEL6/dependencies
```

But, when I try to run ./configure, I am getting the following error:

```
checking for ATK... no
configure: error: Package requirements (atk atk-bridge-2.0) were not met:

No package 'atk-bridge-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables ATK_CFLAGS
and ATK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
```

atk 2.18 is cleary added in the PKG_CONFIG_PATH and also LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

So, I though atk-bridge-2.0 is separate and found the packag: at-spi2-atk and at-spi2-core. But, no atk-bridge-2.0 is installed.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `atk-bridge-2.0` API is provided by [at-spi2-atk](https://git.gnome.org/browse/at-spi2-atk), not by ATK.

Your build environment is fairly broken, and it seems you're installing each component into its own prefix. You shouldn't. Create a temporary build root, and add that to `$PATH`, `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`. Then, use the same prefix for every component.

You should look at how [jhbuild](https://git.gnome.org/browse/jhbuild) works.

Comment: Hi..thanks, I have installed it successfully. But only after installing atk, dbus, at-spi2-core, at-spi2-atk in order, otherwise, the bridge part is missing in the installation.