# meld - GLib-GIO-ERROR**: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system

Tags: unix, glib, meld, gsettings

I have installed meld 3.14.2, at last (on NFS share in Redhat 6.3 server), after nearly 40 hours of efforts , installing each and every dependency and at last seems to be successful. But one finale error needs to be solved:

```
(meld:20703): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

There was answer here: [GLib-GIO-ERROR**: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953925/glib-gio-error-no-gsettings-schemas-are-installed-on-the-system)

I am not aware of these jargons before. So, please explain in detail what to do.

Do I need to set the variable `$XDG_DATA_DIR` or not? And if, why and what should be the value?

And I can find that the compiled file is already located in `MyApp/share/glib-2.0/schemas`.

However, I have also tried the following, even though the compiled schema is already there:

```
glib-complile-schemas <PATH_TO_SCHEMAS> --targetdir=MyApp/share/glib-2.0/schemas
```

But still I am getting the error. I have tried the variable too by setting it to `MyApp` and `MyApp/share/glib-2.0/schemas`. That too doesn't work.

I have also tried reinstalling gsettings-desktop-config. Still error. In my case, it's 3.12 version.

So, what's going on here?? Please explain. I have been sleepless. :(

Thanks you!

And also for your information, I have installed all the dependencies GTK+,ATK,CAIRO,PANGO etc... under the same installation directory with `prefix=<base>/meld/deps`.

Example:

- meld binaries resides as follows: `<base>/meld/bin/`
- cairo binaries are installed as follows: `<base>/meld/deps/bin/`
- atk binaries are installed as follows: `<base>/meld/deps/bin/`

Similarly, you can think of other dependencies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I am unsure why you are installing it to its own prefix... but just setting `GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR` to the full path to the schema dir should work.

Comment: Wow!!! worked like charm! I realized that we can point only one directly to the variable, so I have copied the schema XML from all locations i.e, meld and its dependencies to a common location in my dependencies, and ran glib-compile-schemas --targetdir=<the shared location>...and pointed the variable to the shared location...It's working now from all servers :) Thank you!

Comment: You should really take the advice from http://stackoverflow.com/a/35772800/172999 and stop installing each component to its own prefix; otherwise you'll keep running into errors like this. That's not how these libraries were meant to be installed.

Comment: @ptomato Hi, yes I have followed the same. But missed this variable: $XDG_DATA_DIRS. And unfortunately, the tool GUI starts, but functionality doesn't work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794241/meld-gi-glib-gerror-icon-meld-change-apply-right-not-present-in-theme-wha Can you help on this please.